# Phonegap background task

Tags: ios5, cordova, ios4

I'm developing an iOS phonegap application which receives messages from a node.js/socket.io server. Everything works fine except when the application is "suspended". The user must re-activate the application to see incoming messages. Alerts throw only when the application is active.

Is there any workaround to throw alert messages even if the application is suspended.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long research and some tests, it seems that it is impossible to keep an application running on background if it does not track localisation, use voip, play music and a limited number of other scenarios... at least on iOS.
I'm going to use APNS instead.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 8 you can wake up the app with a notification or by a time interval and then e.g. performFetchWithCompletionHandler